How can I improve my Python code for checking if a number is prime؟
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return False
    if n <= 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0 or n % 3 == 0:
        return False
    i = 5
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        i += 6
    return True

number = int(input("Enter a number:\n"))
if is_prime(number):
    print(f"{number} is prime")
else:
    print(f"{number} is not prime")

The function seems to work correctly, but I'm looking for advice on any potential issues or improvements that could be made. Additionally, I'm unsure if my approach is the most efficient for large numbers.
Could you point out any potential problems in my code, or suggest ways to optimize it further?

Consider popping this into the search bar [python] test prime. Testing for primes has been discussed a lot here.

is_prime as written will return true for n = 7 * 7.

This question would be a better fit for [codereview.se], once you've fixed the bug that @user2722968 identified.

for i in range(5, math.isqrt(n) + 1, 6): will run considerably faster on average by avoiding repeatedly computing squares and comparing in Python-level code, and instead only performing a single square root computation and computing sequential values in C-level code. It's not really an algorithmic improvement (it's still O(n**0.5), though technically addition will be more efficient than multiplication for large values, but this code is too slow for large values anyway), but it will help out. Really you just want Miller-Rabin or Baillie-PSW or the like to be efficient for large inputs.

@wizzwizz4 It has already been done 200+ times. If they want to know how to improve it, just look at the existing answers.

You can use the seive algorithm, instead:
def get_sieve(n):
    if n < 3:
        return

    primes = [True] * (n + 1)
    primes[0] = primes[1] = False

    for i in range(2, int(n ** 0.5) + 1):
        if primes[i]:
            for j in range(i * i, n + 1, i):
                primes[j] = False

    res = [i for i in range(n + 1) if primes[i]]
    return res


print(get_sieve(10 ** 2))


Prints
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

